Ordenar los commit del más nuevo al más antiguo en GitHub
Cuando voy a la web de mi repositorio en GitHub tengo ordenados los commit del más antiguo al más reciente, hay alguna forma de que cuando veo estos commits estén ordenados del más reciente al más antiguo.

Y que no es ese el orden default?? Algo has cambiado
